# Is this definition of morality from a known philosopher or philosophical school?

Tags: ethics

I've [heard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWNW-NXEudk) the following definition of morality:

> A particular action or choice is moral or right if it somehow promotes happiness, well being or health, or it somehow minimizes unnecessary harm or suffering, or both.
>
> A particular action or choice is immoral or wrong if it somehow diminishes happiness, well being or health, or it somehow causes unnecessary harm or suffering, or both.

Is this definition proposed by any known philosophers/schools of philosophy, or it's an original?

Comment: I don't think any moral philosopher would define a particular action or choice as moral [morally good] or right if it merely 'somehow' promoted happiness, &c. Suppose S will be happy if she sees someone today wearing a purple shirt; and suppose that today I wear a purple shirt from choice. S sees me in my purple shirt and is happy. How have I done a moral [morally good} action or made a moral [morally good] choice?

Answer (score 7):

The quoted example appears to be type of [Consequentialism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/); more elaboration would be required to specify it further (for example, it may or may not be Utilitarianism).

(If the SEP article is too dense, a more introductory account can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism).)

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the more common ways of formulating of [Utilitarianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism).

Jonathan Bentham and John Stuart Mill are two well-known Modern Utilitarianists. The only contemporary philosopher that comes to mind is Peter Singer.